# Java NPE when Loading a Dependency from Maven from within Zeppelin on AWS EMR

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I've created a Spark cluster on EMR using the following command:

```
aws emr create-cluster \
  --name "2-node Zeppelin cluster (turn me off after use)" \
  --instance-type m3.xlarge \
  --release-label emr-4.2.0 \
  --instance-count 2 \
  --log-uri s3://redacted/logs \
  --ec2-attributes KeyName=redacted \
  --use-default-roles \
  --applications Name=Spark Name=Zeppelin-Sandbox\
  --configurations file://aws-emr/configs/spark.json \
  --no-auto-terminate
```

This got me a 2-node Spark (v 1.5.2) cluster on EMR, with Apache Zeppelin (v 0.5.5) UI.

However, when trying to load a dependency from Maven into the ZeppelinContext using `z.load()`, (straight after spinning the cluster - I did nothing in between) [as per the docs](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.5-incubating/interpreter/spark.html) I got a Java Null Pointer Exception seemingly due to some Sonatype Repo error:

[image]

- I looked at several links trying to figure out what may be the problem but I couldn't solve the issue.
- I am running Yarn and I have another, unrelated, Spark app (Spark Streaming) also running on Yarn.
- I have also tried calling `z.reset()` before that, to no avail. In fact, it even threw an error: `error: value reset is not a member of org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext`
- I tracked the file and line mentioned in the error message and it turned out to be [this line](https://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-aether/blob/master/aether-impl/src/main/java/org/sonatype/aether/impl/internal/DefaultRepositorySystem.java#L352), which looks like this:

  ```
  ArtifactRequestBuilder builder = new ArtifactRequestBuilder( trace );
  DependencyFilter filter = request.getFilter();
  DependencyVisitor visitor = ( filter != null ) ? new FilteringDependencyVisitor( builder, filter ) : builder;
  visitor = new TreeDependencyVisitor( visitor );
  result.getRoot().accept( visitor ); //<<<<------- THIS
  ```

**Has anyone gone through this and/or has any info that could help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a workaround, if not the reason for the problem:

- SSH into your EMR instance and edit file `/usr/lib/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh` changing the last line so that it looks like this:

  ```
  export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="$SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10:1.5.2"
  ```

This will make Spark load that (and any one packages you specify, delimited by commas), into your Spark interpreter, which is what I wanted.

> **P.S.:** Thank you Mon Soo Lee for mentioning this in [this mailing list post](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-zeppelin-users/201511.mbox/%3CCALf24sbhKZP1xuEqQDXpcXzX9x4yjkd8pMVUtmZrKmN=avP9tQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: Apparently it's a problem with AWS that will be fixed in the next (4.3.0) release label:  http://apache-zeppelin-users-incubating-mailing-list.75479.x6.nabble.com/Zeppelin-notes-version-control-scheduler-and-external-deps-td1730.html

Comment: **UPDATE:** This is not an issue anymore in *emr-4.3.0*